# How to disable scroll bar indicator in GUITabPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using a cocoa pod which is called "GUITabPagerViewController" in my LineUpViewController and I am able to use it properly. However, I want to disable tab bar indicator. I know how to disable tab bar indicator if I inherit directly from Scroll View since it has necessary methods, but I inherit from GUITabPagerViewController in my view controller and there isn't any method associated with that. Thus, I came up with an idea of inheriting from GUITabPagerViewController and GUITabScrollView both, however Objective C does not allow multiple inheritance.

Is there an idea how I can disable that scroll bar indicator ? I put related pictures below:

[image: Scroll bar indicator]

[image: My .h file]

[image: My .m file]

I just want to get rid of silly looking indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk about Pods but in the source code of this 3rd party component, there is a method called `- (void)reloadTabs`. That method has the following snippet.

```
if ([[self dataSource] respondsToSelector:@selector(tabColor)]) {
    [self setHeaderColor:[[self dataSource] tabColor]];
  } else {
    [self setHeaderColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
  }
```

Here it takes the variable `tabColor` if you have the method `- (UIColor *)tabColor` in the ViewController you are settting as data source and delegate of your TabpageVIewcontroller. By default the color is purple that's why you are seeing indicator. Change the color to `[UIColor clearColor]` instead of purple and you won't have to see it. Like this:

```
- (UIColor *)tabColor {
  // Default: [UIColor orangeColor];
  return [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Otherwise you can directly manipulate the source and modify it in `-(void) reloadTabs` as following:

```
if ([[self dataSource] respondsToSelector:@selector(tabColor)]) {
        [self setHeaderColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
      } else {
        [self setHeaderColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
      }
```

You will get a view like this: [image]

Comment: Thank you @NSNoob . It worked :) However, I have a different question: Why does GUIScrollView exist? I mean, how GUITabViewPageController and GUIScrollView are connected? I could not see a connection between them. There has to be a connection since we can scroll between tabs, am I right?

Comment: @EmrahAkgül GUITabPagerViewController is delegate of GUITabScrollView. The variable named "header" in GUITabPagerViewController is instance of GUITabScrollView. As you guessed it correctly, it helps you scroll between tabs and it is controlled by the delegate methods to adjust appropriately.